# Free AS3 Particle Engines

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm looking for a free AS3 particle engine that can render effects such as smoke, fire, water ripples, waterfalls and more. I need something robust like [Partigen 2.5](http://desuade.com/partigen), only available without licensing.

So far I've found:

- [Flint Particle System](http://flintparticles.org)
- [Stardust Particle Engine](http://code.google.com/p/stardust-particle-engine/)

Any other recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made great use of [www.flintparticles.org/](http://flintparticles.org/) in the past. Its really flexible, easy to use, and has a lot of nice features built in.

@OP - the engine you linked (Partigen) looks quite nice. But, with some "massaging" Flint can do just about everything there.

Answer (score 1):

Was it so hard to google it? http://flintparticles.org/examples

Comment: I've googled it. I'm just looking for the best options from the knowledgeable programming community on here.

Comment: You should list what you've done so far to try to find an answer, for example, "So far I found flintparticles (link it), is there anything else I should look at?